rqt reconfigure widget doesnot show any parameter
I am trying to constrain the lidar point cloud within certain X,Y,Z limits. My C++ code for this is:
// Set up parameter descriptor for integer_param with a specific range
    rcl_interfaces::msg::ParameterDescriptor x_descriptor;
    rcl_interfaces::msg::FloatingPointRange x_range;
    x_range.set__from_value(-6).set__to_value(6).set__step(0.0);
    x_descriptor.floating_point_range = {x_range};

    rcl_interfaces::msg::ParameterDescriptor y_descriptor;
    rcl_interfaces::msg::FloatingPointRange y_range;
    y_range.set__from_value(-5).set__to_value(5).set__step(0.0);
    y_descriptor.floating_point_range = {y_range};

    rcl_interfaces::msg::ParameterDescriptor z_descriptor;
    rcl_interfaces::msg::FloatingPointRange z_range;
    z_range.set__from_value(-2).set__to_value(2).set__step(0.0);
    z_descriptor.floating_point_range = {z_range};
    
    this->declare_parameter<double>("x_min", 1.5, x_descriptor);
    this->declare_parameter<double>("x_max", 2, x_descriptor);
    this->declare_parameter<double>("y_min", -1.5, y_descriptor);
    this->declare_parameter<double>("y_max", 1.5, y_descriptor);
    this->declare_parameter<double>("z_min", -1.5, z_descriptor);
    this->declare_parameter<double>("z_max", 1.5, z_descriptor);

Then using rqt_reconfigure, I was able to change these parameter dynamically. Unfortunately, the widget is not showing anything now. There are no refresh button or something now. Please see the attached image below.

There are no warning on the terminal, when I run ros2 run rqt_reconfigure rqt_reconfigure. Also, when I run ros2 param list, i can see all the parameter, including the one declared for my use-case. Here is the section of relevant output from ros2 param list.
/feature_extraction:
  qos_overrides./parameter_events.publisher.depth
  qos_overrides./parameter_events.publisher.durability
  qos_overrides./parameter_events.publisher.history
  qos_overrides./parameter_events.publisher.reliability
  use_sim_time
  x_max
  x_min
  y_max
  y_min
  z_max
  z_min

Why is rqt_reconfigure not showing anything? Am I missing sth?

github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_reconfigure/issues/4
resolved my issue.
